# C++: Is it normal to pass array reference to function

Tags: arrays, c++11, pass-by-reference

Arrays can be passed as pointer to a function or even as reference. Passing it as reference gives an alias on which sizeof and count operators will also work. This makes pass by reference look superior.

However, pass by pointer seems to be the norm in books. Why? Is there something I particularly need to know about pass by reference for arrays?

Answer (score 5):

Passing by reference means that your function can only accept fixed-size arrays (that's why it knows their size, because the compiler enforces it). Passing by pointer means otherwise. Also, passing by pointer lets you pass `nullptr`, for better or worse.

Comment: ! Won't a dynamically allocated array be accepted as parameter for pass by reference? How come? A reference is after all an alias.

Comment: @quantum231 Dynamically allocating an array already returns a pointer, so no.

Comment: There is no auto-allocation requirement, but there is a type issue. example:

`void f(int (&arg)[5]);`
`void g() {f(*new int[1][5]);}`

Comment: @ToddFleming Could you elaborate a bit? 1. What were you trying to say with the example; 2. An example of when it's possible to get an array without automatic storage?

Comment: This example compiles; there is no requirement that arrays passed by reference have automatic storage. Instead, the real issue is that `new` returns a pointer to the first element of the outermost array; this throws away some (not all) size information.

Comment: Wow, haven't thought of that. Thank you; will revise.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `std::vector` and like to pass by const reference.  That said, if my api may at some point be called by c code, using pass by const pointer may make sense, though you then have to also want to send down the size.  If the function may be called with an `std::array` or a `std::vector`, you could decide to send down a pointer (and size), or a set of iterators (begin/end).

If we are talking about using std::array, the template argument requires the size of the array.  This would mean in a normal function, you'd need a fixed size:

```
void myfunc( const std::array<int, 5>& mydata ){...}
```

However, if we do a templated function, templating on size, that is no longer a problem.

```
template<unsigned int SZ>
void myfunc(const std::array<int, SZ>& mydata) {...}
```

If we are talking about stack allocated c-style arrays...  Good C++ style is to prefer std::array/std::vector to c-style arrays.  I would recommend reading [C++ Coding Standard by Herb Sutter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) chapter 77 on page 152 speaks about the subject.  When using c-style arrays, sending down the pointer and size is the standard way to go.